# Can hashicorp vault be embedded within a Java Web application

Tags: jakarta-ee, hashicorp-vault, spring-vault

We are planning to use HashiCorp's vault for storing secrets using the key value pair v2 engine. Currently I'm able to start the vault as a separate server as described in the tutorials but is there any way to embed/bundle vault within in a java web application because we don't like the idea of having it run separately. I know it is way more better but just wanted to know if there is a possibility to have it embedded

On the client side i'll be using spring-vault for accessing and storing secrets. I tried a basic operation of adding and retrieving a secret using spring-vault and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Vault is a separate service written in a separate language. It needs to live beyond the lifecycle of your application, preferably in High Availability mode.